# Apache Felix and Glassfish V2

Tags: glassfish, osgi, apache-felix

We are using Glassfish V2 and are about to evaluate OSGI. 
I plan to get started with Apache Felix as OSGI container.
What is the best solution to get Apache Felix to excute within Glassfish V2?

Glassfish V3 is not an option...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest ditching Glassfish altogether and use `Karaf` with `Felix`. See [this Q+A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612120/osgi-what-are-the-differences-between-apache-felix-and-apache-karaf)

We moved away from Glassfish a couple of years ago and we ended up with a server that is far more lightweight and faster than what we had in Glassfish.

I can't tell you much about the specifics of our implementation as I did not implement it, but I'm in the process of learning it to 'distribute the knowledge'.